# TaskAssigning sample debug

Tags: optaplanner

I'm debugging the TaskAssigning sample to Sundstrand some behavior.
But I don't understand one thing.

During startup all employee in task object are null.
When start solving the getEmployee of Task is called and employee field is != null.
But the setEmployee is never called!
I commented the set and the project still works.
How can OptaPlanner set the employee without using the set method.

Thanks,
S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a Java question than an OptaPlanner question. Java supports [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html), through which user code can access pretty much anything (under some circumstances). OptaPlanner (and [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/)) use reflection to read and write fields; even though it does support going through getters and setters, it can also avoid them completely.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, yes is more Java question. If I move the Annotation [inverserelationshadowvariable] from the field to the getter I see OptaPlanner call the setter.